# React: workaround for CSS pointer-events: none in IE9

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-9, pointer-events

I would appreciate some help in implementing a workaround for pointer-events: none to my React button component in IE9.  I use this button to submit a form. I pass down a prop to the button and, based on the value of this prop, the button will have different styling.

I use componentWillReceiveProps to change the state and the styling of my button when it receives the new prop value.

What I am trying to achieve here: submitState is '' then clicks are allowed. submitState is 'loading' or 'success' then disable click on the button.

The issue I have is that I end up trying to query selectors that don’t exist when the component mounts. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make my code below work?

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      submitState: this.props.buttonState,
      text: 'Click',
      textLoad: 'Loading',
      textSuccess: 'Success'
    }
    this.noclickLoad = this.noclickLoad.bind(this);
    this.noclickSuccess = this.noclickSuccess.bind(this);
  }

  loading () {
    this.setState({
      submitState: 'loading'
    });
  }
  success() {
    this.setState({
      submitState: 'success'
    });
  }
  disabled() {
    this.setState({
      submitState: 'disabled'
    });
  }
  nothing() {
    this.setState({
      submitState: ''
    })
  }

  noclickLoad() {
    document.querySelector('.myButtonContainer.loading .myButton').style.cursor = 'default';   
    document.querySelector('.myButtonContainer.loading .myButton').disabled = 'true';
  }
  noclickSuccess() {
    document.querySelector('.myButtonContainer.success .myButton').style.cursor = 'default';   
    document.querySelector('.myButtonContainer.success .myButton').disabled = 'true';
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.submitState === this.props.submitState) {
      return
    } 
    switch (nextProps.submitState) {
      case 'loading':
        this.loading();
        break;
      case 'success':
        this.success();
        break;
      case '': 
        this.nothing();
        break;
      default: 
        return
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.noclickLoad);
    window.addEventListener('load', this.noclickSuccess);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={`myButtonContainer ${this.state.submitState}`}>
          <button className="myButton">
            <div className="buttonText">{this.state.text}</div>
            <div className="buttonTextLoad">{this.state.textLoad}</div>
            <div className="buttonTextSuccess">{this.state.textSuccess}</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the css

```
.myButtonContainer .myButton {
    background-color: red;
}
.myButtonContainer .myButton .buttonTextLoad, .myButtonContainer .myButton .buttonTextSuccess {
    display: none;
}

.myButtonContainer.loading .myButton {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.myButtonContainer.loading .myButton .buttonTextLoad {
    display: block;
}
.myButtonContainer.loading .myButton .buttonText, .myButtonContainer.loading .myButton .buttonTextSuccess {
    display: none;
}
.myButtonContainer.success .myButton {
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.myButtonContainer.success .myButton .buttonTextSuccess {
    display: block;
}
.myButtonContainer.success .myButton .buttonText, .myButtonContainer.success .myButton .buttonTextLoading {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `.loading` and `.success` of button container won't coexist at the same time. Use `if` statement to make sure that the selector's element exists before change it.

```
// Same to .success
let button = document.querySelector('.myButtonContainer.loading .myButton');
if (button) {
    button.style.cursor = 'default';   
    button.disabled = 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

<div id='inputArea' className={`input-area${loading ? ' pointerEventNone' : ''}`} aria-disabled={loading}>
    //code..
</div>

<button className="myButton" onClick={()=>setLoading(!loading)}>Toggle Button for Disable</button>
```

css:

```
.pointerEventNone {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```